# How to populate in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I have 2 RethinkDB Table:

```
Left: 
{
  id: String,
  title: String,
  key: String // for mapping with table Right
}

Right:
{
 id: String
 title: String
 description: String
}
```

RethinkDB has eqJoin() and zip() method, which help us clone all field of table Right to table Left:

```
r.db("myDB").table("Left")
.eqJoin("key", r.db("myDB").table("Right"))
.zip()
```

The result will look like this:

```
[{
  id: "the-id",
  key: "Right-object-id",
  title: "Title of Right Object",
  description: "Description of Right Object"
  // => title of Left Object was deleted
}]
```

The question is:
**How to simulate a query like *populate()* of *Mongoose*?**

I want a result look like this:

```
[{
  id: "the-id",
  key: {
     id: "Right-object-id"
     title: "Title of Right Object"
     description: "Description of Right Object"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Using eqJoin**

You can map the result, using `eqJoin`:

```
r.db("myDB").table("Left")
.eqJoin("key", r.db("myDB").table("Right"))
.map(function (row){
  return row('left').merge({ key: row('right') })
})
```

**Sub Queries**

While you can use `eqJoin` in RethinkDB, subqueries are usually easier to work with and more powerful. You can use the `merge` term to add a new key and then use a subquery to set the value of that key:

```
r.db("myDB").table("Left")
.merge(function (row){
  return {
    'key': r.db("myDB").table("Right")).get(row('key'))
  }
})
```

I usually never use `eqJoin`. It's not as easy to work with as just using subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution, but I'm finding a better solution than it:

```
r.db('myDB').table("Left").eqJoin("Right",r.db("myDB").table("Right"))
.map(function(row){
  return row("left").merge({key: row("right")})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you consider following is a better solution because I don't see what wrong with your query, as long as you use `index`, the query is fast and efficient.

```
r.db('myDB').table("Left").map(function (doc) {
   return doc.merge({key: r.db('myDB').table('Right').get(doc('key'))})
})
```

This query, however, always use primary index on right table, by default, because we use `get`